# Does this sound similar to Beethoven's compositions?

Tags: classical-music

These background sound very good. Any idea as to whether these are original compositions? It definitely sounds similar to Beethoven's music.

https://youtu.be/c5rZMUqaRtM

Comment: nope, not at all

Answer (score 2):

Authorship is credited on the youtube posting it self ("enjoy the music by Anirudh Ravichander.")

Anyway it is not much related to Beethoven or other Classical or Romantic period composers. If anything it sounds like Celtic music, not only the sound and instrumentation but the melodies themselves.